# How to send Javascript Keycodes to a window?

Tags: javascript, key

I have a window open and I would like to send Javascript keycodes to this window.

For example:

```
 send(37)   #would force the left arrow
```

I cant seem to find any way to do this..
Any programming language that works is fine.

Comment: Any language that can send javascript keycodes is all i need

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to trigger key events on the page, you can do that. If you want to trigger certain things in the browser (like clicking the address bar), that's also possible, but a completely different thing. Some context would help providing a useful answer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Scanning a barcode? Something for a game? If you explain the purpose you'll get more help on what is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with window.postMessage() ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: I am using another application not a webbrowser

Comment: It isn't same origin policy that prevents keypresses from being simulated, it is the general principle that a script should not be able to mimic user interaction (or should at least be able to do this as little as possible and as transparetly as possible)